# How to add existing swarm service to a network?

Tags: docker, swarm

I know, when creating a servcie, we could specify the network. But if have already had some services, then how to add them to a network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to update the service, like so:

```
docker service update --network-add my_network my_service_name
```

You can [read here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_update/) about what else you can do with the update command